# IE: iFrame Showing, and No Borders *Says Boss*

Tags: html, css, live, modal-dialog, colorbox

Hello Everyone and Good Morning,

I am working with the page:
http://702wedding.com/live/

And it works in ALL my browsers Execpt IE. I dont have IE so I am kinda flying in the dark as far as fixing it. My boss is saying something about the iframe border showing in IE and w/e else any of you IE'ers can see. Also the font on the index page BEHIND the modal is showing tiny font.

I am on a mac and desprately need a way to see IE in the future, BUT can anyone help me fix this this morning?

**Problems:**
iFrame Showing in IE
Tiny Font behing Modal in Index Page.

Thank You all very much, as always.

^_^

Comment: Unrelated: I'm seeing a JS error in IE7. I think it's due to the comma you have after `innerHeight:624,` in your colorbox initialization.

Comment: Have you considered just obtaining IE? Pretty key to being a successful web developer...

Comment: @jonezy No "lolz" were intended, I'm completely serious. If he considers "cross-browser testing" to be asking the SO community to fire up IE and debug his stuff for him, he isn't going to get very far.

Comment: I thought it was pretty funny (while being 100% correct and true)

Comment: You really ought to get IE to test it in, the blue border around the modal for example only shows up in IE9 beta, not any earlier versions. You can download time limited Virtual PC images containing IE6, IE7 and IE8 from Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of border:none, try setting the border to an explicit value:

```
style="border:0px solid #fff; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:21px;"
```

Also, try setting the display selector to block.

I have this style on an iFrame, and the border does not display in IE:

```
style="border:0px solid #FFF; display:block; left:0; top:0px; height:100%; width:100%;
```

Also, you have an extra comment in your Javascript, causing an error:

`$(".example5").colorbox({innerWidth:686, innerHeight:624 ->,<- }`

Answer (score 2):

I see the frame border in IE7. Try setting `border: 0` and `background: transparent` in your styles for the iframe. Then add `allowtransparency="true"` as an attribute to the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any browser try https://browserlab.adobe.com/en-us/index.html. 
you can get a preview of your link in set of defined browser (almost all ).

Answer (score 1):

set your border="0" and frameborder="0" on the iframetag

Answer (score 1):

The page is at least functional in IE6:

[image: modal dialog in ie6]

Note that the nav at the top of that dialog is broken. IE6 doesn't listen when you tell it a frame has no CSS "border" - you have to explicitly tell it it has no frameborder, so use `border="0" frameborder="0"` on the iframe tag.

Behind the modal dialog, the text isn't "tiny" - in fact, it's rendered similar to how FF renders it (though, it's IE6, so the text is hard to read/aliased, of course)

And, for future reference, you can use [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) to get screenshots of the page in a variety of different browsers/versions, including IE[4-9], last time I checked.

Otherwise, you could look into IEs4Linux which'll let you run IE6 and 7 on Linux, provided you have a valid Windows license.